# Fine uploader, idiomatic way to add download button to each file uploaded

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I've successfully implemented [fine uploader](http://fineuploader.com) into my project.  I'm using the [addInitialFiles](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addInitialFiles) method to populate it with previously uploaded files.

What I would like to do is add a download button to each file preview rendered, both as a user add's files and 'on load' when prepopulated using addInitialFiles.  Adding the button to the mark up template is pretty trival, but I'm stuck on what the most idiomatic way would be to:

- Listen for the click event on the download button I've added to the markup (e.g. use a fine uploader API method, or my own listener?)
- How I can associate the necessary information with each button/thumbnail to envoke a file download.

I'm storing the files download url in a mongo collection that that im returning and populating the addInitial files method with.

In case it comes up:  I'm not looking to have fine uploader 'handle' the download, I'm simply trying to weave the download functionality into it's UI :)

Appreciate any/all advice/pointers!

Comment: Listen for what click event? Also: Where is the download URL for each file coming from?

Comment: @RayNicholus HI Ray, have updated my comments, I hope this helps clarify!

Comment: Why do you need to listen for a click event? You should be using an anchor link to download a file.

Comment: @RayNicholus, I don't 'need' too - this is simply the way I've come at the problem :)  So...is there a way to take the data sent to the uploader by addInitialFiles, grab the the download url and add it to the anchor link?  I may be not be thinking about this the 'right' way, hence asking whats most idiomatic, thanks for the patience!

Comment: Since this was fixed, would be nice to have the code of your working example. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add an anchor link to your template somewhere inside the `<li>`.
2. Listen for `qq.status.UPLOAD_SUCCESS` status changes.
3. On success, update the anchor link to point to the appropriate download endpoint. You can find the anchor link for a specific file using [`getItemByFileId`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getItemByFileId).

You'll need to be sure your server returns the proper `Content-Disposition` header when responding to a download GET request.

Comment: Ray - thank you, this is exactly where I ended up on my, great to know it was the idiomatic approach :)

Comment: How to make this working with Initial files? I'm getting an error when trying to use `getItemByFileId()`.

Answer (score 0):

May this help to someone to add a custom download button to each uploaded file.

I have tested for FineUploader version 5.16.2.

Used ref links - [callback events](https://docs.fineuploader.com/tag/5.1.3/features/styling.html) & [initial file list](https://docs.fineuploader.com/features/session.html)

Code for file uploader is as (used two events for the download button):

```
var defaultParams = {};
$('#fine-uploader-gallery').fineUploader({
    template: 'qq-template-gallery',
    thumbnails: {
        placeholders: {
            waitingPath: 'waiting-generic.png',
            notAvailablePath: 'not_available-generic.png'
        }
    },
    validation: {
        itemLimit: 10,
        // acceptFiles: 'image/*',
        // allowedExtensions: ['mp4','jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
    },
    session: { /** initial file list **/
      endpoint: '/uploaded_files', 
      params: defaultParams
    },
    request: { /** new upload file request **/
        endpoint: '/upload_files'
    },
    callbacks: {
        /** Event to initial files with download link 
        array(
            array('id' => xxx, 'name' => xxx, 'size' => xxx, 'thumbnailUrl' => xxx, 'uuid' => xxx, 'url' => fileUrl),
            array('id' => xxx, 'name' => xxx, 'size' => xxx, 'thumbnailUrl' => xxx, 'uuid' => xxx, 'url' => fileUrl2),
            ...
        }
        **/
        onSessionRequestComplete: function(id, name, responseJSON){
            id.forEach((item, index) => {
                var serverPathToFile = item.url,
                    $fileItem = this.getItemByFileId(index);
                if (responseJSON.status == 200) {
                    $($fileItem).find(".qq-download-option") /** Custom Anchor tag added to Template **/
                        .attr("href", serverPathToFile)
                        .removeClass("hide");
                }
            });
        },
        /** Event to newly uploaded file with download link
            responseJSON : array('success' => 'true', 'filename' => xxx, 'unique_id' => xxx, 'url' => fileurl)
        **/
        onComplete: function(id, name, responseJSON, xhr){
            var serverPathToFile = responseJSON.url,
                $fileItem = this.getItemByFileId(id);
            if (responseJSON.success) {
                $($fileItem).find(".qq-download-option") /** Custom Anchor tag added to Template **/
                    .attr("href", serverPathToFile)
                    .removeClass("hide");
            }
        }
    },
    deleteFile: {
        enabled: true,
        forceConfirm: true,
        method: 'DELETE',
        endpoint: '/delete_files',
        customHeaders: {},
        params:defaultParams
    }
});
```