# Fine-uploader Initial File List onStatusComplete null result

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I want to do the same feature as found [in this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377213/fine-uploader-idiomatic-way-to-add-download-button-to-each-file-uploaded) ;

But in the onStatusChange callback the objects are null.

```
callbacks: {
    onStatusChange: function(id, oldStatus, newStatus) {                            
        console.log('new status of ' + newStatus + ' for ID: ' + id);
        console.log(this.getItemByFileId(id));
    }
```

I get the following output

`new status of upload successful for ID: 0`

`fine-uploader.min.js:2 [Fine Uploader 5.14.2] Caught exception in 'onStatusChange' callback - Cannot read property 'className' of null`

I know session response from my server is OK, b/c fine-uploader displays my file, filename and the delete button.

Is what I'm trying to do supported?

Here's my full fine-uploader code for reference:

```
`
    var uploader_132963 = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: document.getElementById("uploader_132963"),
        session: { endpoint: 'https://localhost/session',  params : {  account: 'DEMO9', index: 1, psuuid: UUID_UPLOAD1},},
        template : 'qq-template1',
        debug: true,
        request : {
                endpoint: 'localhost',  
        },

        autoUpload: true,

        retry: {
                enableAuto: true
        },

        multiple: false,

        concurrent: {
                enabled: false
        },

        chunking: {
                concurrent: {
                        enabled : false,                    
                },

                enabled: true,
                mandatory: true,
                partSize: 2000000,
                success: {
                        endpoint: 'https://localhost/success'
                }
        },

        deleteFile: {
                enabled: true,
                endpoint: 'https://localhost',
                method: 'POST',

        },

        extraButtons: {
                folders: false
        },

        validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['3g2','asf','avi','bmp','doc','docx','flv','gif','jpeg','jpg','m4a','m4v','mj2','mov','mp3','mp4','pdf','png','ppt','pptx','svg',],
                allowEmpty: false,
                itemLimit: 1,
                sizeLimit: 1024000000,
        },

                callbacks: {
                    onStatusChange: function(id, oldStatus, newStatus) {
                        if (newStatus == qq.status.UPLOAD_SUCCESSFUL) {
                            var fileItem = this.getItemByFileId(id); // will throw exception here
                        }
                    }
                }
})
```

`

Comment: most likely the DOM element for the file has not been added yet

Comment: @RayNicholus I thought that was the point of using the onStatusChange event, that the element would be there at that point in time.

Add an anchor link to your template somewhere inside the <li>.

Listen for qq.status.UPLOAD_SUCCESS status changes.

On success, update the anchor link to point to the appropriate download endpoint. You can find the anchor link for a specific file using getItemByFileId.

Comment: https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submitted

Comment: The onStatusChange works fine for a new file, but I'm loading files from in Initial file list (session), which does not trigger a "submitted" event.

Comment: You're not checking for UPLOAD_SUCCESS anywhere in your code.

Comment: @RayNicholus - I've tried it both ways, same result.  Updated code sample above to reflect checking for UPLOAD_SUCCESS.  The ID still comes back zero. The onSubmitted callback doesn't get called at all when files are added via a Session (initial file list)

Comment: "The ID still comes back zero". This is a problem because...?

Comment: @RayNicholus -  OK,, thank you; I didn't know a valid Id for a file could be zero (i'm new to fine-uploader) Seems as though getItemByFileId is not defined under `this` in the onStatusChange event.  If I move my code to the onAllComplete, then `this.getItemByFileId(succeeded[0])` works just fine.

Comment: `getItemByFileId` is accessible in all callbacks.

Comment: @RayNicholus - then why does `var fileItem = this.getItemByFileId(id);` (as the only meaningful line of code in the `onStatusChange` callback throw an exception? `Caught exception in 'onStatusChange' callback - Cannot read property 'className' of null`  The Id of the file is zero, and the same line of code works OK in the onAllComplete function?

Comment: Your assertion that the API method is not available is incorrect. As I mentioned much earlier, the error you are seeing is due to a lack of representation in the DOM for that particular file.

Comment: I am having this issue too - the getItemByFileId seems to be failing when called when newStatus is "rejected"

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue as described here. The solution was as pointed out by bobflorian. This is how I handle both canned files loaded from the server normal uploaded files:

```
onAllComplete: function( arrSucceeded, arrFailed,) {

            if (arrSucceeded!==null && $.isArray(arrSucceeded)){

                for (var i=0,x=arrSucceeded.length;i<x;i++){

                //Get the template markup for the uploaded file
                var fileItem = this.getItemByFileId(arrSucceeded[i]);
                //Get the generated uuid. This is the same uuid that we save in the PHP SESSION. It points to the actual uploaded file
                var uuid = this.getUuid(arrSucceeded[i]);

            }
}
}
```

I'm using version 5.16.2. Ray, you did a fantastic job with this library.

Answer (score 0):

Moving my code to the onAllComplete callback gives the desired result when loading files via the Initial File List.  The onStatusChange doesn't seem to have the getItemByFileId function available under `this` at that point in time.  It will throw an exception of
    `Caught exception in 'onStatusChange' callback - Cannot read property 'className' of null`

Comment: This is not correct. The context needed to call all API methods in Fine Uploader is set for all events/callbacks. You are misinterpreting the error message.

Comment: I am having this issue too - the getItemByFileId seems to be failing when called when newStatus is "rejected"